# Flutter Auto Login Remember Me function using Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm trying to do autologin function for my flutter web app using provider. I couldn't find any articles or videos about this and I wonder how it should implemented.
What I'm trying to do is check the shared preferences before launching site. App uses URL routing so I have to do the checking whatever url the user goes.
Here is my main code.

```
void main() {
  setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppStateProvider())],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final RouteInformationProvider? routeInformationProvider;
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.routeInformationProvider}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins'
      ),
     // home: HomeView(),
      routerDelegate: RoutemasterDelegate(
        routesBuilder: (context) {
          return buildRouteMap(context);
        },
      ),
      routeInformationParser: RoutemasterParser(),
      routeInformationProvider: routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my AppStateProvider class

```
class AppStateProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool loading = false;
  AppStateModel? appState;

  checkCaches() async {
    loading = true;
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? acToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
    if (acToken != null) {
      appState?.isLoggedIn = true;
      appState?.accessToken = acToken;
      final String? comToken = prefs.getString('companyToken');
      appState?.companyToken = comToken;
      loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      appState?.isLoggedIn = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  storeCaches(String acToken, String? comToken) async {
    loading = true;
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('accessToken', acToken);
    prefs.setString('companyToken', comToken!);
    appState?.isLoggedIn = true;
    appState?.accessToken = acToken;
    appState?.companyToken = comToken;
    loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Any ideas about the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I thought **Consumer** might work for you

like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: WebLocalStorage().userInfoNotif,
  builder: (BuildContext context, User value, Widget child) {
    return value == null
        ? HBLoginPageNew()
        : HBHomePage(
            user: WebLocalStorage.instance.user,
          );
  },
);}
```

this is my autologin code. I'm using ValueNotifier. Consumer works with the ChangeNotifierProvider.